# IS there an API option to change who a Docusign envelope is displayed at being sent by?

Tags: docusignapi

When using the Docusign API (in my case, via the Sandbox/demo env), in the signing view at the top of the screen it displays the name & company of the user account that was used to authenticate with the API.

However, because this is embedded signing from my app, I would have thought we'd only have one user account - for the app. So I want to change what appears at the top there - the information on the sender of the envelope. Either to be the user account that exists in my app that created the envelope, or just to state what company sent the document.

Are there options on the API to do this? I can't see any reference to anything like this in the [envelopeDefinition](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#/definitions/envelopeDefinition) JSON structure in the REST API docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DocuSign **SOBO - Send On Behalf Of Functionality**

> The Send On Behalf Of feature permits automated sending through the API by one account user on behalf of another account user.

More information [here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/sobo)